# how to run ngrok using java

Tags: java, ngrok

i wrote a java program to run ngrok with http 8080 . I'm getting follow error after successfully execute the ngrok.exe .
How to take particular output and print in console instead whole output ?

```
   String[] command = {
        "src/Ngrok/ngrok.exe",
        "src/Ngrok/ngrok.exe http 8080"
    };

    String line;
    Process p;
    BufferedReader input = null;

    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

        input = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            logsStatus.replaceSelection(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (null != input) {
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

output && error in following way

```
   NAME:
   ngrok - tunnel local ports to public URLs and inspect traffic

COMMANDS:
   authtoken    save authtoken to configuration file
   credits  prints author and licensing information
   http     start an HTTP tunnel
   start    start tunnels by name from the configuration file
   tcp      start a TCP tunnel
   tls      start a TLS tunnel
   update   update ngrok to the latest version
   version  print the version string
   help     Shows a list of commands or help for one command
```

Error is this :

```
 ERROR:  Unrecognized command: src/Ngrok/ngrok.exe http 8080
```

Comment: You can only run one command at a time. Anything after the command is assumed to be a parameter to that call. Simply just run the second command!

Comment: I tried that way also . but i usally get this error`java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "src/Ngrok/ngrok.exe http 8080": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified`

Answer (score 2):

A simpler solution is to just use [java-ngrok](https://github.com/alexdlaird/java-ngrok) (full disclosure, I am the developer), which is a Java wrapper for ngrok. It gives you programmatic access to the API, the tunnels, everything. It's available on [Maven Central](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.alexdlaird/java-ngrok) (docs are [here](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.github.alexdlaird/java-ngrok/latest/index.html)), and you can use it like this:

```java
final NgrokClient ngrokClient = new NgrokClient.Builder().build();
final CreateTunnel createTunnel = new CreateTunnel.Builder()
        .withAddr(8080)
        .build();
// Open a HTTP tunnel on port 8080
// <Tunnel: "http://<public_sub>.ngrok.io" -> "http://localhost:8080">
final Tunnel httpTunnel = ngrokClient.connect(createTunnel);
```

Full docs on [javadoc.io](https://javadoc.io/doc/com.github.alexdlaird/java-ngrok/latest/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is not working because the command `ngrok http <port number>` opens a new terminal as an output.
I had the same problem, but after searching on web, I found this `ngrok` command `curl -s localhost:4040/api/tunnels` that return a `JSON` object defining all the informations that you want, including the public url. You run this command after `ngrok` http and do same approach it will work.